# Lower model accuracies with tensorflow2.3+keras2.4 than tensorflow1.15+keras2.3

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I created two anaconda environments for tensorflow2x and tensorflow1x respectively. In tensorflow2x, the `tensorflow 2.3.2` and `keras 2.4.3` (the latest) are installed, while in tensorflow1x, the `tensorflow-gpu 1.15` and `keras 2.3.1` are installed. Then I run a toy example [mnist_cnn.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.3.1/examples/mnist_cnn.py). It is found that the former tensorflow2 version give much lower accuracy than that the one obtained by the latter tensorflow 1.

Here below are the results:

```
# tensorflow2.3.2 + keras 2.4.3:
Epoch 1/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 54us/step - loss: 2.2795 - accuracy: 0.1270 - val_loss: 2.2287 - val_accuracy: 0.2883
Epoch 2/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 2.2046 - accuracy: 0.2435 - val_loss: 2.1394 - val_accuracy: 0.5457
Epoch 3/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 2.1133 - accuracy: 0.3636 - val_loss: 2.0215 - val_accuracy: 0.6608
Epoch 4/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 1.9932 - accuracy: 0.4560 - val_loss: 1.8693 - val_accuracy: 0.7147
Epoch 5/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 1.8430 - accuracy: 0.5239 - val_loss: 1.6797 - val_accuracy: 0.7518
Epoch 6/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 1.6710 - accuracy: 0.5720 - val_loss: 1.4724 - val_accuracy: 0.7755
Epoch 7/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 53us/step - loss: 1.5003 - accuracy: 0.6071 - val_loss: 1.2725 - val_accuracy: 0.7928
Epoch 8/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 1.3414 - accuracy: 0.6363 - val_loss: 1.0991 - val_accuracy: 0.8077
Epoch 9/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 53us/step - loss: 1.2129 - accuracy: 0.6604 - val_loss: 0.9603 - val_accuracy: 0.8169
Epoch 10/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 53us/step - loss: 1.1103 - accuracy: 0.6814 - val_loss: 0.8530 - val_accuracy: 0.8281
Epoch 11/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 1.0237 - accuracy: 0.7021 - val_loss: 0.7689 - val_accuracy: 0.8350
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 52us/step - loss: 0.9576 - accuracy: 0.7168 - val_loss: 0.7030 - val_accuracy: 0.8429
Test loss: 0.7029915698051452
Test accuracy: 0.8428999781608582


# tensorflow1.15.5 + keras2.3.1
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 84us/step - loss: 0.2631 - accuracy: 0.9198 - val_loss: 0.0546 - val_accuracy: 0.9826
Epoch 2/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0898 - accuracy: 0.9731 - val_loss: 0.0394 - val_accuracy: 0.9866
Epoch 3/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0674 - accuracy: 0.9799 - val_loss: 0.0341 - val_accuracy: 0.9881
Epoch 4/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0563 - accuracy: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.0320 - val_accuracy: 0.9895
Epoch 5/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0465 - accuracy: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.0343 - val_accuracy: 0.9889
Epoch 6/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0423 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.0327 - val_accuracy: 0.9892
Epoch 7/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0387 - accuracy: 0.9882 - val_loss: 0.0279 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 8/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0351 - accuracy: 0.9893 - val_loss: 0.0269 - val_accuracy: 0.9909
Epoch 9/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0330 - accuracy: 0.9902 - val_loss: 0.0311 - val_accuracy: 0.9895
Epoch 10/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0292 - accuracy: 0.9915 - val_loss: 0.0256 - val_accuracy: 0.9919
Epoch 11/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0293 - accuracy: 0.9911 - val_loss: 0.0276 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/step - loss: 0.0269 - accuracy: 0.9917 - val_loss: 0.0264 - val_accuracy: 0.9915
Test loss: 0.026934823030711867
Test accuracy: 0.9918000102043152
```

What caused the poor results for the tensorflow 2.3.2 + keras 2.4.3?? Is there any compatibility issue between tensorflow and keras here?

According to the [author of keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0), users should consider switching their Keras code to `tf.keras` in TensorFlow 2.x. In the above toy example, if
`from tensorflow import keras` in place of `import keras`, it also leads lower accuracy. It seems `tf.keras` gives poorer accuracy than `keras`? Maybe I run a wrong toy example for Tensorflow 2.X??

Update:
I also note if I decrease tensorflow to the version 2.2.1 (along with keras 2.3.1). They will produce about the same result. It seems there are some major changes from keras 2.3.1 to keras 2.4.0 (https://newreleases.io/project/github/keras-team/keras/release/2.4.0).

What are the specific main differences between keras 2.3.1 and keras 2.4.x??

Which versions of tensorflow are compatible with keras 2.4.x??

Comment: According to logs it looks like you have different amount of data for 2 experiments.

Comment: I have updated the logs for the first scenario. They are trained on the same data.